# Laravel 8 Socialite Facebook redirect didn't work/return null

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-8, facebook-php-sdk, laravel-socialite

I have an app using Laravel 8 as the backend. I already have auth process using a custom table named "accounts," I want to use some social login processes, starting with Facebook. The thing is, I am facing some problems coding it. My controller isn't redirecting correctly to Facebook and returning `{"data": null, "error": null}`. I searched on this issue and have already changed some of the code to solve this, but the problem persists.

**Routes**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginSocialController;

Route::get('account/{provider}/login', [LoginSocialController::class, 'redirectToProvider'])->name('social_login');
Route::get('account/{provider}/login/callback', [LoginSocialController::class, 'handleProviderCallback'])->name('social_login_callback');
```

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
use App\Services\AccountService;
use App\Services\AuthService;

use Exception;

class LoginSocialController extends Controller
{
    public function redirectToProvider($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->redirect();
    }

    public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        $providerAccount = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();
        dd($providerAccount);
    }
}
```

**services.php**

```
return [   
    'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
        'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.mailgun.net'),
    ],

    'postmark' => [
        'token' => env('POSTMARK_TOKEN'),
    ],

    'ses' => [
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
    ],

    'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('FACEBOOK_CALLBACK')
    ],

    'google' => [
        'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('GOOGLE_CALLBACK')
    ],

    'apple' => [
        'client_id' => env('APPLE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('APPLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('APPLE_CALLBACK')
    ],

    'github' => [
        'client_id' => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('GITHUB_CALLBACK')
    ],

];
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but it seems to be something with the project not being web and using the laravel only as backend. Has anyone with this same issue?

---

### EDIT

When I use `dd()` on the `Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->redirect()` I get an object that looks like:

`https://www.facebook.com/v3.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456789&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F%2Fapi%2Faccount%2Ffacebook%2Flogin%2Fcallback&scope=email&response_type=code&state=nesi0U0nBm64Y9jHq1G` (edited)

The weird thing is I don't get this response just calling the endpoint. So I had to use `dd()`.

Comment: you are not "returning" a redirect from your controller method, so how would it redirect?

Comment: that was a test I was doing calling as a variable, but even with "return" the redirect don't work

Answer (score 0):

Your callback route

```
Route::get('account/{provider}/login/callback', [LoginSocialController::class, 'handleProviderCallback'])->name('social_login_callback');
```

must be the same in your FB App that you created before in [Facebook developer](https://developers.facebook.com/)

[image]

and also check the App secret and App id in your `.env` file

Comment: already checked this before, when the callback isn't set properly in the developers facebook page, the return is a page saying the URL was not properly set